# Swap two images by drag and drop in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using ReactJs, When user drag the image and then drop on another image, they should swap.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arr: [
                {
                    name: 'src1',
                    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/200x300'
                },
                {
                    name: 'src2',
                    src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'
                },
                {
                    name: 'src3',
                    src: 'http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg'
                },
                {
                    name: 'src4',
                    src: 'http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg'
                }
            ],
            dragImgName: null,
            dragImgSrc: null,
            dropImgName: null,
            dropImgSrc: null,
            dragImgObj: null
        }

    }
dragWord(item) { 
//got the object of dragged image array
        this.setState({ dragImgName: item.name });
        this.setState({ dragImgSrc: item.src });
    }
    dropWord(event, item) {
        //Item got the object of that image on which drag going to happen.
        // console.log(item.src);
        event.preventDefault();
        var tempDropImg = item.src;
        var tempDragImg = this.state.dragImgSrc;

        this.setState({ dropImgSrc: item.src })
        this.setState({
            arr: this.state.arr.map(el => {
                console.log(el, this.state.dragImgSrc);
                // return (el.src === tempDropImg ? { ...el, src: tempDragImg } : el)
                return (el.src === tempDropImg ? Object.assign({}, el, { src: tempDragImg }) : el)
            })
        });

        this.setState({
            // arr: this.state.arr.map(el => (el.src === tempDragImg ? { ...el, src: tempDropImg } : el))
            arr: this.state.arr.map(el => (el.src === tempDragImg ? Object.assign({}, el, { src: tempDropImg }) : el))
        });
}
render() {
        return (<>
            <div>
                <p>Drag and drop the pictures in order to show.</p>
            </div>
            {
                this.state.arr.map(item => {
                    return (<div key={item.name} onDragOver={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
                        name={`${item.name}`} onDrop={(event) => this.dropWord(event, item)} >
                        <div className="mover boxA" draggable="true" onDragStart={() => { this.dragWord(item) }} >
                            <img src={item.src} alt={item.name} style={{ height: 140, width: 140 }} />
                        </div>
                    </div>)
                })
            }

        </>);
    }
}export default App;
```

I tried every possible thing, searched a lot but I got this solution in React Native. I used **update** method also, still nothing happened. See my [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-meadow-wrg6t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) code for my updation. 
**Note- Comment the setState of line 55 in code for change.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are setting the state three times on the `dropWord` method, and the third time you are calling `setState`, you are overriding the call that you've done previously to change the `arr` variable.

You don't need to call `setState` three times on the `dropWord` method, I would suggest you to create the list with the swapped images and then set the state. Setting the state will render the component so you should try to minimize the set state calls.

Change your `dropWord` method to the following code, it should work:

```
 dropWord(event, item) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let tempDropImg = item.src;
    let tempDragImg = this.state.dragImgSrc;
    this.setState({
      dropImgSrc: item.src,
      arr: this.state.arr.map(el => {
        if (el.src === tempDropImg) return { ...el, src: tempDragImg };
        if (el.src === tempDragImg) return { ...el, src: tempDropImg };
        return el;
      })
    });
  }
```

The same logic aplies to the `dragWord` function. You don't need to call `setState` two times. It's better to change to:

```
  dragWord(item) {
    this.setState({ dragImgName: item.name, dragImgSrc: item.src });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem.Yes I know Due to multiple setState it override the previous one. But I didnt get any way to get rid of this.And you replaced that code with if else, but i want to use somthing like ```this.setState({
            arr: this.state.arr.map(el => {
                console.log(el, this.state.dragImgSrc);
                // return (el.src === tempDropImg ? { ...el, src: tempDragImg } : el)
                return (el.src === tempDropImg ? Object.assign({}, el, { src: tempDragImg }) : el)
            })```  means either spread opr. or Obj. any idea? @Diogo

Comment: I've edited the answer, check if that is what you want, I don't see a way to do it without the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and It already solved my issue with your first answer. 
@Diogo 
```this.setState({
      dropImgSrc: item.src,
      arr: this.state.arr.map(el => {
        el.src === tempDropImg ? { ...el, src: tempDragImg } :
        el.src === tempDragImg ? { ...el, src: tempDropImg } : el ;
      })
    })``` this way you can replace your if else condition from your edited answer.

Comment: @RajatSharma thanks for the feedback, I've edited the answer to insert your suggested answer. Glad it helped, good luck with your project

Comment: hey @Diogo i got a new project on the base of that test which i solved from your solution thanks for that ! Have a good day ahead! :D How much expr. you have BTW?

Comment: Great to hear that :D I've been working for 3 years, two of them in front-end. You can take a look at my profile, it has my personal website in there.

Comment: hey @Diogo that's good to hear! Batman , Lol I like that :p ,, BTW, Is there any way to contact you personally ?

Comment: Yeah, on my personal website `mrperes.com` there is a contact form. You can send me an e-mail by clicking on the e-mail button